# Python Tuple to JSON output

Tags: python, json

How do I turn this:

```
data = ((1, '2011-01-01'), (2, '2011-01-02'), (1, '2011-01-15'), (3, '2011-02-01'))
```

into this:

```
{
    "item": [
     "1",
     "2",
     "1",
     "3",
    ],
    "settings": {
     "axisx": [
      "2011-01-01",
      "2011-01-02",
      "2011-01-15",
      "2011-02-01"
     ],
     "axisy": [
      "0",
      "100"
     ],
     "colour": "ff9900"
     }
}
```

Or rather, are there any helpful resources that I can read so that I would be able to produce that JSON output? So I know I need to 'transform' my data into the right data structure. After that is it as easy as `json.dumps(data)`

Thanks

Comment: Where does the `axisy` bit come from?

Comment: I figured :) See conversion code below...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use the [json library](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html).

Then convert your data using something like this:

```
somedict = { "item"     : [ x[0] for x in data ],
             "settings" : { "axisx" : [ x[1] for x in data ],
                            "axisy" : [ 0, 100],
                            "colour" : "ff9900" }
           }
```

and call:

```
print json.dumps(somedict)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed. I'm still a beginner in Python as you can see!

Comment: am new to python...can we use these libraries (`json` or `simplejson`) to serialize/deserialize objects which are extensively used by python developers say pandas dataframe, series etc.

Answer (score 14):

There is a [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) library.

```
import json

jsonObj = json.dumps(data)
```

Thats for json serializing. If you want output be formatted in some other way than you initial `data` variable, you should create another object, initialize it with values from `data` in the way you need and than use json library for serialization.