# Exporting data from neo4j to csv instead of json

Tags: python, list, csv, neo4j, cypher

I'm using `neo4jdb-python` packages to query the Neo4j database. For example, considering the below code

```
import neo4j
connection = neo4j.connect("http://localhost:7474")
cursor = connection.cursor()
for i in cursor.execute("MATCH a RETURN a LIMIT 1"):
    print i
```

But the output is in the form of a tuple. i.e.

```
({u'text': u'Stoyanov, S., Hoogveld, B., Kirschner, P.A., (2010). Mapping Major Changes to Education and Training in 2025, in JRC Technical Note JRC59079., Publications Office of the European Union: Luxembourg.', u'identifier': u'reference/lak/226'},)
```

How do I get the output in csv format.This is possible with the web view of neo4j. and the output is like,

```
"{""text"":""Stoyanov, S., Hoogveld, B., Kirschner, P.A., (2010). Mapping Major Changes to Education and Training in 2025, in JRC Technical Note JRC59079., Publications Office of the European Union: Luxembourg."",""identifier"":""reference/lak/226""}"
```

However I want to do it via a client program as I need to embed it into another program. If it is not possible with `neo4jdb-python`, then what other options are available.

Comment: you want the keys as headers and the values as columns yes?

Comment: @Padraic to be more specific I want the output as 
"{""text"":""Stoyanov, S., Hoogveld, B., Kirschner, P.A., (2010). Mapping Major Changes to Education and Training in 2025, in JRC Technical Note JRC59079., Publications Office of the European Union: Luxembourg."",""identifier"":""reference/lak/226""}"

Comment: So you want json? Where is the csv coming into play?

Comment: @NicoleWhite When you export as "CSV" from the Neo4j web view, you get that as output. The JSON O/P is quite weird (and more than 1000 characters for this particular query which is 10 times the size of CSV.)

Comment: When I export a csv from the browser, I get a csv, not json. Which button are you pressing? Can you provide a screen shot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That CSV isn't actually coming from a particular API - it's being translated into CSV format on the client side.

The appropriate code is in [exportable.coffee](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/master/community/browser/app/scripts/directives/exportable.coffee#L48) if you want to take a look:

```
    $scope.exportCSV = (data) ->
      return unless data
      csv = new CSV.Serializer()
      csv.columns(data.columns())
      for row in data.rows()
        csv.append(row)
```

And that refers to [CSV.coffee](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/master/community/browser/app/scripts/services/CSV.coffee). I guess you should be able to do something similar in Python perhaps [using json.dumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087903/python-tuple-to-json-output) like this:

```
> import json
> t = ({u'text': u'Stoyanov, S., Hoogveld, B., Kirschner, P.A., (2010). Mapping Major Changes to Education and Training in 2025, in JRC Technical Note JRC59079., Publications Office of the European Union: Luxembourg.', u'identifier': u'reference/lak/226'},)
> json.dumps(t)
 '[{"text": "Stoyanov, S., Hoogveld, B., Kirschner, P.A., (2010). Mapping Major Changes to Education and Training in 2025, in JRC Technical Note JRC59079., Publications Office of the European Union: Luxembourg.", "identifier": "reference/lak/226"}]'
```

Comment: Thanks, But is there a direct way to export as CSV atleast in Java or any other language?

Comment: No I don't think so. Neo4j server only returns JSON AFAIK. It shouldn't be too hard to translate that to CSV though or?

Comment: Just use opencsv and return what you get from the database via the node properties that you want to export to json. See here for some code: https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools/blob/master/src/main/java/org/neo4j/shell/tools/imp/format/CsvFormat.java#L39

Answer (score 6):

The Neo4j Server returns only JSON, as Mark Needham mentions in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26828362/4099593).

Hence any code to do convert it to CSV must be on the client side. This can be done using the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module. Note that `neo4jdb-python` package is compatible with Python2.7 only.

A minimal code for obtaining the data is

```
import neo4j
connection = neo4j.connect("http://localhost:7474")
cursor = connection.cursor()
data = list(cursor.execute("MATCH a RETURN a LIMIT 1")
```

Note that as mentioned in the question the returned values are in the form of tuples. The minimal code to create the csv file is

```
with open("test.csv","w") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter = ',',quotechar = '"',quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writerow(t[0].keys())
    for i in t:
        writer.writerow(['{"%s":"%s"}'%(k,v) for k,v in i.iteritems()])
```

The explanation for the code is simple, open a file. Using [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter), create a `writer` object. Write the header first using [`writerow`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow). Finally loop through the dictionary and write the rows.

The output obtained is

```
"{""text"":""Stoyanov, S., Hoogveld, B., Kirschner, P.A., (2010). Mapping Major Changes to Education and Training in 2025, in JRC Technical Note JRC59079., Publications Office of the European Union: Luxembourg.""}","{""identifier"":""reference/lak/226""}"
```

which is similar to that obtained using the `exportable.coffee` script.