# Selection Sort Recursive Python

Tags: python, recursion

I have this Python code, is a recursive form of the Selection Sort Algorithm, but it doesn't work, can someone help me?

```
def selection(lista):
    return selection_aux(lista,0,len(lista))
def selection_aux(lista,i,n):
    if i == n or lista[0]==None:
        return lista
    else:
        num_menor = menor_f(lista,i,n,i)
        temporal = lista[i]
        lista[i] = num_menor
        print(num_menor)
        lista[num_menor] = temporal
        return selection_aux(lista,i+1,n)
def menor_f(lista,j,n,menor):
    if j == n:
        return menor
    if lista[j] < lista[menor]:
        menor = j
        return menor_f(lista,j+1,n,menor)
```

Test:

```
>>> selection([1,2,3])
```

Output

```
lista[num_menor] = temporal
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not NoneType
```

Comment: Can you please add more details as to how it is not working. Something like, what output you expected but what output you got, some logical error, or something like that.

Comment: Without reading your code carefully, isn't this a bit too long and complicated for something as simple as selection sort?

Comment: Yes, it is, but the idea is write that algorithm by using tail recursion !!

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation was wrong, you did not return anything is  `if lista[j] < lista[menor]` was False so you were setting `num_menor` to `None` as all python functions that don't return a value return None by default .

```
def menor_f(lista,j,n,menor):
    if j == n:
        return menor
    if lista[j] < lista[menor]:
        menor = j
    return menor_f(lista,j+1,n,menor) # dedent
```

Cannot follow you variable names as I don't speak what seems to be french, but making the change works for `selection([4,3,2])`

```
print(selection([4,3,2]))
[2, 3, 4]
```

Fails for `selection([ 8,3,4,2,5,6]) -> [3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 8]` so you need to do some debugging.

Comment: Actually is Spanish! I'm from Costa Rica!, Thank you for help me!!

Comment: Err.. What is *dedent*? A short for *de-indent*?

Comment: @BhargavRao, if you write python it is a word ;)

Comment: Oh damn.. I knew *outdent*. So even I hafta change my vocab to *dedent*. :/

Comment: @BhargavRao, stick with me, I will lead you down the path of pyenlightenment ;)

Comment: Yep. You have been doing that since we first [met](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26816433/export-neo4j-to-csv-using-python#comment42203585_26816433) :D

Comment: @BhargavRao,ah  back when 12k+ imaginary rep points was only a dream!